# Can I still get paid after quiting first shift?

Tags: salary, new-job, resignation, canada

I lost my old job due to COVID. They had advised us to apply at a particular chain of grocery stores. I did the online application and had a very brief phone call with a recruiter. I received an email telling me to come in at a certain time for my first shift.

I was given next to no information. I was not told anything relating to what my position was, pay, benefits, works hours or the schedule. I tried contacting the recruiter and the person who sent the email but I got no reply. I attended my shift and was taken to the office. I think what happened is they weren't sure which department to put me in and one department head jumped in and tried to scoop me up. I sensed a great deal of deception from this individual. For example when he was explaining benefits to me someone interrupted and said he was explaining it wrong. He seemed a bit crazy so I told him this wasn't going to work and left.

Also there was a confirmed COVID case in the store last week and I noticed most employees were not wearing a mask.

Should I still try to get paid? I left after 1 hour. Where I live the law is an employee must get paid for minimum two hours. They never took my banking information, which the email said I needed to provide to get paid. Should they still legally pay me?

One particular thing I felt strange about was the manager got me to lift up a few boxes to see if I was strong enough to carry them. Why would they be testing me if I already got the job?

I told the recruiter what happened and she called me back to explain things, like what the pay was. The pay she told me was different than the pay they had told me at the store. I told her I sensed a lot of deception from the manager and would consider working at a different location. This is a very large chain.

It's been a long time since I've worked in grocery stores and know things are a bit different in the way they do business (even without COVID). Is it too much to expect to get some kind of written offer letter with all the information about pay and position? The government is supporting people who lost their job but it depends on how much they are currently working.

Is there anyone I should report this to, like the HR department? Any general advice about how to not get angry at this stuff?

Here is a link to the [applicable labour laws](http://www.bclaws.ca/EPLibraries/bclaws_new/document/ID/freeside/00_96113_01).

Comment: Legality aside, do you expect to gain anything by pursuing getting paid for one hour? Seems to me like the time spent in getting this paid out combined with the *severe* reputational damage would mean it'd best to simply forget this ever happened. Is this an academic question or is there a particular reason you'd want to get paid for one hour?

Comment: @Lilienthal if I understand what you're asking, if they would've returned my e-mails or answered my phone calls all of this would have been avoided. At minimum I did invest coming in for work.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but what I meant is that you'd be putting a lot of effort into getting barely an hour's pay. And that's before you factor in the damage this could do to your reputation if the news got around. This seems like a "live and learn" moment, not a "get even" one...

Answer (score 4):

It isn't obvious to me from your description that you were ever formally hired rather than being called in for an interview where it was expected you'd be hired and do your first shift immediately.  It is possible that you were hired, are owed 2 hours of pay, and then quit.  But it seems like there is a decent possibility that you attended an interview and decided not to take the job before it was offered.

As a practical matter, trying to get the company to give you 2 hours of pay if you never signed any paperwork indicating that you were an actual employee is going to be a challenge.  I'd be shocked if it didn't take you a lot more than 2 hours of phone calls and writing letters expressing your opinion.  It seems unlikely that this is a particularly productive use of your time or your mental energies.

More importantly, though, I'd be very cautious about what getting those 2 hours of pay would do to your unemployment benefits.  If your position is that you were hired by the store, worked an hour, and then resigned then you left your position voluntarily which generally means that you're not eligible for unemployment.  You'd have to argue that "sensing deception" was just cause for voluntary resignation.  That seems like a rather tough case to make.  Given how busy the unemployment office is at the moment, I wouldn't want to spend the time, not to mention the mental and emotional energy, of trying to convince them that you resigned for just cause.

As for how to not get angry...  If the store was rapidly trying to hire to deal with the pandemic, it's not shocking that the ad hoc hiring process was disorganized-- that's the nature of on the fly actions.  What you sensed as deception could well have been confusion or a manager stumbling in an unfamiliar situation.  If the manager really was being intentionally deceptive, losing an hour of your time to avoid getting sucked into a situation where you were dependent on him seems like a great outcome.  If the manager was just confused or disorganized because of the pandemic, I'd suggest doing your best to give everyone-- yourself included-- permission to be imperfect at this point in time.

Comment: No it was certain that I was hired. The e-mail says those words. I don't mean to be rude but if they weren't expecting me when I showed up, that's their problem.

Comment: "If your position is that you were hired by the store, worked an hour, and then resigned then you left your position voluntarily which generally means that you're not eligible for unemployment." good point I'll check on that. That's kind of what annoyed me so much about how they were unclear what the pay was, with government benefits it's particularly important to be certain with all the details at this time.

Comment: @beestrees1 - It isn't obvious to me that an email saying "you're hired" without an offer letter, a signed contract, an agreement on the rate of pay or the job title, and without any new hire paperwork is a valid employment contract.  It might be (or it might be under some circumstances) but that would be a question that probably ought to be addressed to an employment lawyer.  My reading based on your description was that you were in negotiations for a job and couldn't come to a satisfactory agreement.  And that reading would probably benefit you in terms of unemployment.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? In addition to the e-mail saying "you're hired" there was also the entire application process and the fact that I sent in my resume.

Comment: @beestrees1 - Because employment is a contract and a contract requires a meeting of the minds.  If you haven't agreed on the basic terms of employment (you'll be working as an x for a salary of $y/hour, etc) there has been no meeting of the minds, thus no contract, thus no employment.  It's as if you said you had a car for sale, someone emailed you saying they wanted to buy it, but showed up not knowing what make/ model the car was or how much you were charging.  That's my (very much not a lawyer) bias though, again, an employment lawyer might disagree.

Answer (score -2):

> Should I still try to get paid?

Sure, give it a shot. The only thing you have to lose is time.